# Activate "disabled selected" when other select option is picked

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-events

How to make `select` gets the value of `disabled selected` when an other `select` is picked?

The reason to do that, is when you pick an option from any `select` list then you try to click again on the same option it doesn't change (and I understand it won't change because actually you didn't change anything, so I was thinking to return it again to default value so `on change` would work again).
Example: I click `Blue` then I click `30`then I want to click again `Blue` but it doesn't change, I still have `30` instead. I forgot to mention that only one result (`div`) should be shown.

```js
   $(function() {
   $('.content2').val("");
 
        $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        
        $('.content2').hide();
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
          //  $('#testL').option.value="";
         // $('#testL').prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });
    
    
     $(function() {
        $('#testL').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
            $('.content2').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

```css
   .content2 {
  display: none;
}
.colors{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
<option value ="" disabled selected > Select </option>
   <option value="red">Red Option</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>

<div id="red" class="colors"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors"> blue.. </div>

<select name="testL" id="testL">
  <option value ="" disabled selected > Select </option>
  <option value =20>test for 20</option>
  <option value =30>test for 30</option>
</select>
<div id="20" class="content2" > hello 20 </div>
<div id="30" class="content2" > hello 30 </div>
```

Comment: I tried .click instead of .change, but this isn't a good practise, I'm sure there's a better solution.. please any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer, it's just by adding `$("#testL").val("");` and `$("#colorselector").val("");`(or you can add anything to `val` if you want to select any other option).
So here's the update:

```js
   $(function() {
   $('.content2').val("");
 
        $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        
        $('.content2').hide();
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
          //  $('#testL').option.value="";
         // $('#testL').prop("disabled", true);
           $("#testL").val("");
        });
    });
    
    
     $(function() {
        $('#testL').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
            $('.content2').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
             $("#colorselector").val("");
        });
    });
```

```css
   .content2 {
  display: none;
}
.colors{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Select id="colorselector">
<option value ="" disabled selected > Select </option>
   <option value="red">Red Option</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>

<div id="red" class="colors"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors"> blue.. </div>

<select name="testL" id="testL">
  <option value ="" disabled selected > Select </option>
  <option value =20>test for 20</option>
  <option value =30>test for 30</option>
</select>
<div id="20" class="content2" > hello 20 </div>
<div id="30" class="content2" > hello 30 </div>
```